# How to increase legend symbols without overlaying shape

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, symbols

I'm doing a plot for a shiny app and I need to increase the size of symbol in a ggplot legend. I have multiple aesthetics (shape and color) that depending on some conditions need to be merged into one legend or kept separated in two legends.

I've tried to use:

```
guides(shape = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 3))
```

but this override all the different shapes.

Depending on my initial condition, my df can be like the one below

```
print(dt)
        xAll yAll factors groupVar colVar shapeVar
16.30% 33.95 16.3   30:20    30:20  30:20    30:20
16.50% 35.06 16.5   30:20    30:20  30:20    30:20
16.60% 35.84 16.6   40:20    40:20  40:20    40:20
16.90% 36.50 16.9   40:20    40:20  40:20    40:20
17.50% 37.39 17.5   40:20    40:20  40:20    40:20
```

or like the following one:

```
print(dt)
         xAll yAll       factors groupVar colVar shapeVar
16.30% 33.95 16.3 30:20_0.56_NA     0.56   0.56    30:20
16.50% 35.06 16.5 30:20_0.54_NA     0.54   0.54    30:20
16.60% 35.84 16.6 30:20_0.52_NA     0.52   0.52    40:20
16.90% 36.50 16.9  30:20_0.5_NA      0.5    0.5    40:20
17.50% 37.39 17.5 30:20_0.48_NA     0.48   0.48    40:20
```

Here the code for my plot:

```
ggplot(data.frame(dt)) + 
geom_line(aes(xAll,yAll,group=groupVar, col=colVar)) +
geom_point(aes(xAll,yAll,group=groupVar, col=colVar, shape=shapeVar, size=5)) +
  scale_size_continuous(guide='none') +
  {if(any(shape==col)) labs(shape="HS", colour="HS") else labs(shape="HS", colour="SPR")}
```

The result for the first *dt* without (left) and with (right) the *override.aes* look like this:

[image]

The result for the second *dt* without (left) and with (right) the *override.aes* look like this:
[image]

The symbols in the legend look very small, and I would like to increase them no matter what it's in the legend, keeping the original shape and color.

Any help very much appreciated.

Thanks,

Piera

Answer (score 0):

I solved it just changing the size of the overall aesthetic in the plot.

```
geom_point(aes(xAll,yAll,group=groupVar, col=colVar, shape=shapeVar), size=5)
```

Not ideal, because it increases point size in the plot as well, but I found a compromise between the two.

P